# SQL Injection through default membership.

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, security

I am using memebership.validateuser function to validate the user in Asp.net MVC 3 but I dont find it safe enough for SQL injection.

The method is taking two parameter usernme and password and then services checks for it from the values stored in its memebership table which is encrypted with salt.

Can we have another menthod to to this functionality that will be much more safe than memebership or Asp.net membership validuser service is secure enough and I should stick with it???

Comment: Could you explain what you do not find safe enough? How would an attack scenario look?

Comment: @Ankit Does the `ASP .NET` membership use SPROCS? `Linq-to-SQL`? As Tomalak said, what is unsafe about the way it does it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new method that essentially does what `membership.validateuser` is already doing, why don't you just create a method that sanitizes the entered username and/or password before passing those to `membership.validateuser`?

LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework generates parameterized SQL so you are protected against SQL Injection out-of-the-box.

To answer your last question: stick with it. :)